# How do I add a gem to a group from within a Thor task?

Tags: thor

I'm in a Thor task where I'd like to add gems to the assets group in my gem file (see below).

The gem_group command (known from standard Rails App Templates) doesn't seem work in a Thor task (see error at bottom).

How could i best add a gem to a group in the gem file from within a Thor task?

Any thought welcome - thanks.

```
class ThorBuild < Thor

  desc "add_gems", "Adds the gems I need"
  def add_gems
    puts "Running add_gems"

    gem 'mongoid', '~> 3.0.15'
    gem 'bson_ext'
    gem 'less-rails'
    gem 'devise'

    gem_group :assets do
      gem 'therubyracer', '= 0.10.0', :platforms => :ruby
      gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
    end
  end

end
```

The output looks like this ...

```
Running add_gems
/home/ubuntu/sites/ThorBuild.thor:12:in `add_gems': undefined method `gem_group' for #<Thor::Sandbox::ThorBuild:0x000000007b5110> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor.rb:275:in `dispatch'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/base.rb:425:in `start'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/runner.rb:36:in `method_missing'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/task.rb:29:in `run'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/task.rb:126:in `run'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor.rb:275:in `dispatch'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/base.rb:425:in `start'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/thor-0.16.0/bin/thor:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/thor:19:in `load'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/thor:19:in `<main>'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Solved. Did what I wanted to do in a generator (where the thor utils are available too).

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer rather than a comment.